# Why do openssl and ssh of Git for Windows report different versions of OpenSSL?

Tags: git, openssl

On Windows Server 2008, I have an installation of Git for Windows (Git-1.9.4-preview20140929).

Within a bash shell, `openssl version` reports version **0.9.8zb**, but `ssh -V` reports Open SSL **1.0.1i**.

So, which version accurately reflects the version of OpenSSL that would be used by an SSL connector within JBoss (via torquebox) running on this server?

Why would these two tools, supplied within the same version of Git for Windows not have matching OpenSSL versions?

Comment: They might be linked against different versions of the library, or are even statically linked.

Comment: @Sven, true in general, but not how stock Git for Windows is build and shipped. I'm afraid `@tjg` might have a path lookup precedence issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have an outdated (1.8.X) installation of Git for Windows<sup>1</sup> so this might be not up to date, but from what I see in my installation, `ssh.exe` (which is a build of OpenSSH) depends on `msys-crypto-X.Y.Z.dll` while `openssl.exe` depends on that library and `msys-ssl-X.Y.Z.dll` with these `X.Y.Z` parts matching ("0.9.8" in my case).  These libraries are located in the same directory as the executable files in question: `{gitInstallDir}/bin`.

AFAIK, when building GfW, the build suite pulls and builds exactly one copy of OpenSSL so both the reslting `openssl.exe` and `ssh.exe` are expected to use the same set of libraries provided by OpenSSL.  Hence I sense some sort of `%PATH%` precedence problem.

What I would check:

1. Run

   ```
   type -a openssl
   ```

   and

   ```
   type -a ssh
   ```

   in your Git Bash prompt, and see if they both return something starting with the "/bin/" prefix as the first (or sole) entry of their respective outputs.  If you see something other, like "/c/whatever/other/path/openssl", you have another instance of the `openssl.exe` program available earlier than the Git for Windows' copy thanks to your `%PATH%`; the same applies to `ssh.exe`.

   If yes, fix the contents of `%PATH%`.
2. Get a copy of [`depends.exe`](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and run it against `ssh.exe` and `openssl.exe` from your GfW install to see which libraries they link to, and where those are located.  This might give you the clue as to where to look if something appears to be wrong.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not "msysGit" but "Git for Windows": "msysGit" is a very old name of the project which is used for quite some time to refer to the *development environment* for Git for Windows while the latter term is used to refer to the end product: the Windows port of Git and a binary installer you've used to install GfW.  Please stick to this terminology to not increase the confusion.